# Run a script inside a virtual machine, but called from out of the VM

Tags: bash, virtual-machine

I need to run thousands of times a windows program inside a virtual machine, VM, (I am using VMWare player), and call it with different parameters each time. I wonder if this can be done out of the VM, I mean, if what I need to do inside the VM is for instance

```
cd c:\temp
executable ARG1 ARG2
```

(where ARG1 and ARG2 are the variable input parameters), I want to know if I can do it calling this out of the VM from Linux, something like

```
bash: ./vmwareplayer [call previous msdos script with arguments ARG1 and ARG2]
```

Or if this is possible with other sort of VM.

Comment: This can definitely be done via a client/server application, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: If you install ssh in the vm server, you can connect to it from the main machine.

Comment: https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix111_vmrun_command.pdf

Comment: You could run a script on the host that creates a BATCH file (script) that runs all the jobs and save the file in a directory shared with the VM, then go into the VM just once and start that file...

Comment: You may be overthinking this -- will it not suffice to disregard the host-guest relationship and use a conventional means to issue your command like SSH, message queue, or even some kind of RPC mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to install a ssh server in your VM. Then you just need ssh to your machine an run the program inside the VM.

You can execute a command like:

```
ssh user@NAT-IP command
```

Or just open a session and you will have a command prompt:

```
 ssh user@NAT-IP
```

Make sure that you have configured your Network Adapter in NAT mode.